# Three20: TTSplitViewController's popup view not work in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, three20

It's happened when I turns the iPad into portrait orientation, then I
tap popup view -> table cell, that not work as expected.

I also tested the TTCatalog example that also have this issue.

My Three20's version is 1.0.9